# rsync symlinks to php files

Tags: bash, unix, rsync

I'm trying to rsync my website to the server, while preserving some symlinks. I have reade some documentation and this should do the trick

```
rsync -vra --links
```

Except for one problem: It doesn't copy symlinks that are not directed to a folder, but to a file (.php in this case, but I don't think that is important). It basically breaks.

This link works:

```
htdocs/content/uploads -> /data/sharedstorage/uploads
```

This link gets skipped

```
htdocs/content/config.php -> /data/sharedstorage/config.php
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

P.S: I want to keep the symlinks, so I don't want to copy the files that the original symlink links to.

Comment: Why do you think it gets skipped because it's symlink? Can you give the full rsync command?

Comment: rsync -vrla --delete --update --dry-run --exclude=.git --exclude=htdocs/.htaccess --exclude=.git* --exclude=*.old --exclude=.*.old --exclude=*.dist --exclude=.*.dist  --exclude=www --exclude=.* --exclude=vendor/bin --exclude=vendor/cube --exclude=vendor/johnpbloch --exclude=vendor/koodimonni --exclude=vendor/koodimonni-language --exclude=*.json --exclude=Gruntfile.js --exclude=vvv* --exclude=wp-cli.yml --exclude=*.lock --exclude=*.md --exclude=node_modules --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/tests --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/*.json --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/*.txt

Comment: --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/*.md --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/resources/assets/bower --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/resources/assets/scss --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/resources/assets/js/*/ --exclude=htdocs/content/themes/starter/resources/assets/css/**/*.map ./ user@server:

Is the full command. -l should do the same as --links (tried both) It's not excluding these files if I checked correctly.

Comment: Try "rsync -vvrla ..." to make rsync output the excluded files. Or add more "v"-s to get more debug output.

Comment: It seems to send it as a file: send_files(14, htdocs/content/advanced-cache.php). is there something I can do about that?

Comment: @DannyvanHolten - if the command line is relevant to the question (which it is), then you should [include it in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38826110/edit). Comments do horrible things to formatting, and (as you've seen) are limited in length. Please update your question, and consider requesting that a moderator move it to http://SuperUser.com or http://Unix.stackexchange.com. This is not a programming question, and is therefore off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ghoti thanx. I have however no acces to unix.stackexchange :) So that's why I posted it here.

Comment: Fair enough. If you don't want to open an account at that site, that's up to you. I've voted to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it WILL transfer them as symlinks. Only the feedback that rsync gives doesn't recognise the symlinks. Probably because they have an extension. And thus it will see it as files ...

So the problem is not really a problem after all. More like a "bug" within the verbose function in rsync

Comment: Rsync doesn't care about what you call "extensions". A filename is a filename, whether it has a dot or a carriage return or any other old character in it[*](http://serverfault.com/a/150744). Rsync doesn't detect file type by any pattern in the filename. It [asks the operating system for this info](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&sektion=2).

Comment: So how come it isn't recognized, but it is transferred correctly then?

Comment: I can't replicate your results. It works for me exactly as I would expect, in the test case I created.